# linker command failed: .h file not found

Tags: ios, swift, import, cocoapods, libraries

I had a project with two libraries which were added using Cocoapods:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '8.0'
pod 'Sync'
pod 'DATASource'
```

with bridging-headers file:

```
#import "UINavigationBar+CustomHeight.h"
#import "Reachability.h"
#import <Sync/Sync.h>
#import <DATAStack.h>
#import <DATASource/DATASource.h>
```

Then I had to add new library again with cocoapods:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '8.0'
pod 'Sync'
pod 'DATASource'
use_frameworks!
pod 'THCalendarDatePicker', '~> 1.2.0'
```

When I run pod install it creates new .xcworkspace and I opened it.

Then I've tried to import libraries headers to bridging-header file:

```
#import "UINavigationBar+CustomHeight.h"
#import "Reachability.h"
#import <Sync/Sync.h>
#import <DATAStack.h>
#import <DATASource/DATASource.h>
#import <THDateDay.h>
#import <THDatePickerViewController.h>
```

Then when I run my project it fails with this message:

> DATAStack.h file not found.

Then I moved DATAStack files from Pods target to my project target as shown [here](http://oi62.tinypic.com/35hel9v.jpg). And it didn't work either.

Then I wanted to discard changes by deleting moved files and Cocoapods files, then I've edited my podfile to previous version and run pod install. Then when I run my project again it crashed with this message:

> ld: file not found:
>   /Users/miklekusmenko/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Am_I_Free-axejrdndolpmbnbzdigmgsefhqra/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Am
>   I Free?.app/Am I Free? clang: error: linker command failed with exit
>   code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Can someone help me with my problem?

Comment: Is the "file not found" error the only one in your build?  I usually see that if I have some other error first.  Also, are you getting that when linking your main app or when linking a test bundle?

Comment: @PhillipMills It is the only one error in build and I'm getting that when linking to test bundle.

Comment: In that case, check whether the file path it's complaining about is an exact match for the location and name where the main app is being created.  If not, there's something in the build settings pointing wrong for one of them.  Otherwise...no idea.

Comment: @PhillipMills [Here](http://oi59.tinypic.com/nut5u.jpg) is what I found there. Seems that 'Am I Free?.app/Am I Free? ' isn't there?

Comment: @PhillipMills [Here](http://oi58.tinypic.com/14vqsm1.jpg) are the build settings for tests target. Should I change link for debug to something else?

Comment: In Xcode, there's a "Products" group where your .app file should be visible.  If you right-click the app and choose "Show in Finder" you should see where it really is and update build settings to match.

Comment: From your image, it looks as if the problem is the '?'.

Comment: @PhillipMills I clicked 'Show in finder' on Products/Am I Free.app file and [here](http://oi62.tinypic.com/2zg6g00.jpg) this is where the file is located. Now I should change linking or testing setting in build settings?

Comment: @PhillipMills I've changed the settings like on [this screenshot](http://oi58.tinypic.com/auujoo.jpg), cleaned and build the project but the error is still there.

Comment: @PhillipMills Now it says `ld: can't map file, errno=22 file '/Users/miklekusmenko/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Am_I_Free-axejrdndolpmbnbzdigmgsefhqra/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Am I Free.app' for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Comment: @PhillipMills Any ideas what should I do?(